# How to send email for failed jobs in shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, email

I have a shell script. To this script I am passing arguments from a file. This file contains tables names

The script is working fine. I am able execute the command for all the tables in the file.

`shell script`

```
#!/bin/bash

[ $# -ne 1 ] && { echo "Usage : $0 input file "; exit 1; }
input_file=$1

TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log 
success_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
failed_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log

#Function to get the status of the job creation
function log_status
{
       status=$1
       message=$2
       if [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [ERROR] $message [Status] $status : failed" | tee -a "${failed_logs}"
                #echo "Please find the attached log file for more details"
                #exit 1
                else
                    echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [INFO] $message [Status] $status : success" | tee -a "${success_logs}"
                fi
}


while read table ;do 
  sqoop job --exec $table > /home/$USER/logging/"${table}_log" 2>&1
  g_STATUS=$?
  log_status $g_STATUS "Sqoop job ${table}"
  cp /home/$USER/logging/"${table}_log" /home/$USER/debug/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`/logs/
done < ${input_file}
```

Now I want to send emails to my email address for `failed jobs`.

`Requirements`

```
1) Send email for each failed job i.e If `status log` has failed job for one particular table then I want email sent out saying job for that table has failed. 

2) Or Send out one email for all the jobs that have failed for one input file.
```

Which is the best method to approach. I would like the `2nd` option atleast it will reduce the no of emails to go through.

But better if I know both methods to do

> `edited function log_status`

```
#Function to get the status of the job creation
function log_status
{
       status=$1
       message=$2
       if [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [ERROR] $message [Status] $status : failed" | tee -a "${failed_logs}"
                mail -a mail.txt -s "This is the failed job log" user@example.com < /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log
                #exit 1
                else
                    echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [INFO] $message [Status] $status : success" | tee -a "${success_logs}"
                fi
}
```

If I do this will I get one email for all the failed jobs.

Comment: does it have to be written in shell script also ? You surely can launch a mail agent via the command line in some tweaked maner that'll fit your needs

Comment: @Yvain I would like to have it in the shell script itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also it's possible using `sendmail` command:

```
sendmail user@example.com  < email.txt
```

Using `mail` command:

```
mail -a mail.txt -s "This is the failed job log" user@example.com
```

`-a` is a attachment, `-s` is a subject

And with many attachments:

```
$(uuencode file1.txt file2.txt) | mailx -s "Subject" user@example.com
```

Comment: What does the code do? Does it send email for each failed job or does it send email for all failed jobs of a single file

Comment: where should I include this code in the above script

Comment: It sends one email, include it into `log_status`. If you want many attachments at a time see third option.

Comment: You can prepare command in your `while read table` (concatenate attachment command with all files) then execute it after the loop

Comment: mail -a "/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log" -s "This is the failed job log" user@example.com

Comment: or `mail  -s "This is the failed job log" user@example.com < /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log`

Comment: Your *.fail_log is a a growing log of all error messages for the day. May be you should send  ${table}_log, as an attachment instead of mail.txt (which is propbably empty anyway, if not filled somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple snippet for sending an err.log:

```
 mail -s "stder logs for ps" "name@example.com" < err.log
```

This appends a subject in the first quotes and mails it to the recipient in the second set. In this case I suppose you would have a code block export the error logs via `3>` to a file which I called `err.log` for readability. I would place the above snippet either inside of your script if you are not worried about being too vocal about the errors or neatly outside of the script if you want to be more discrete about how often you are emailing the recipient.

Comment: thank you for you answer. Could you please explain what you code does? Does it send email for each failed job or does it send email for all failed jobs of a single file

Comment: where should I include this line of code in my shell script